# Read multiple file csv in pandas from a directory and store them in a array of list, each file as one observation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, neural-network

I have a folder, i have 30 CSV files in there , all different name.

I want to loop through all the files and read them using pandas separately, and store them in a list of lists. While reading them separately, I want also to remove some variables from them at the same like remove columns which are correlated.

Currently, I am trying to do this.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
path = os.getcwd()


# Get folder path containing text files
file_list = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')
data = []
for file_path in file_list:
    data.append(
        pd.read_csv(file_path).drop(['column1', 'column2'], axis =1))
# now you can access it outside the "for loop..."
for d in data:
    print(d)
```

So, I want to store each data frame as 2 D lists in a list and train my model because each[ [CSV][2] ][3]file is an observation. My CSV file is having(5000,12) observations. have label for each CSV or instance, which is the filename.

Don't know If I am moving in right direction.

```
len(data) 
# 30

label = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
max_length = 25 # shape of data frame after removing two variables
# define the model

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
# summarize the model
print(model.summary())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can create `dictionary of DataFrames` with `keys` from filenames:

```
file_list = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')
dfs = {os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]: 
       pd.read_csv(fp).drop(['column1', 'column2'], axis=1) for fp in file_list}
```

For select use:

```
print (dfs['turbo1'])
```

EDIT:

```
dfs=np.array([pd.read_csv(fp).drop(['column1','column2'],axis=1).values for fp in file_list])
```

Comment: I want them to stored as array of  arrays (or list of lists), so that I can train my NN model on the same. I am editing and putting my next step. Please check.

Comment: I have attached two screenshots above with name Directory and CSV. CSV file has 5000 observations and 27 variables in all. I have 30 CSV files for training, so there are 30 CSV file (5000, 12) as a single instance. The label to classify is the filename, which are three as unique.

Comment: OK, so need `dfs = {os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]: pd.read_csv(fp).drop(['column1', 'column2'], axis=1).values.T.tolist() for fp in file_list}` ? Convert each DataFrame to lists ot lists? Or `dfs = {os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]: pd.read_csv(fp).drop(['column1', 'column2'], axis=1).values for fp in file_list}` for convert to `2d` arrays ?

Comment: Sometimes comments are not copy well, so I add it to answer. Or problem is in your data?

Comment: dfs[0] is not shown and when I try to convert into numpy array, I got empty array.

I want it like: array([df1], [df2], [df3], .....)

where df3 has shape 5000,12 inside that .

Comment: `dfs[0]` ? There is file with name `0` ? If yes, need `dfs['0']`. If need select first row of array in dict  use `dfs['filename'][0]` or `dfs['filename'][:, 0]` for first column

Comment: I am sorry, but why have you made it a dict,  I need it as array in array or list in list. its reading as key value pair I think. My second question, why you transpose it with .T

Comment: I add `dicts` because I think you need it. So if need nested arrays use last edit solution.